# Jquery to hide rows of one table but not another

Tags: jquery

I'm relatively new to JQuery.  I borrowed the code (sorry not to reference the author, but I lost track of where the code came from) on the below fiddle and modified it slightly to achieve my overall goal.

I essentially have two tables, one with an id and class and one with neither.  I cannot easily give the non-id/class table an id/class as I am using JQuery inside of another application and don't have that much control.

What I want is for the search functionality to search and filter ONLY the non-id/class table (first table in below/fiddle).  So in the case of this fiddle, I want the search functionality to search/filter the table that is NOT id="myTable" class="test1" (first table).  Right now it filters both.

I don't know if this code is even the best to do this, so I'm open to suggestions.  Thanks!

```
<label for="kwd_search">Search:</label> <input type="text" id="kwd_search" value=""/>
<table border="1" style="border-collapse:collapse">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Sports</th>
            <th>Country</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Sachin Tendulkar</td>
            <td>Cricket</td>
            <td>India</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Tiger Woods</td>
            <td>Golf</td>
            <td>USA</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Maria Sharapova</td>
            <td>Tennis</td>
            <td>Russia</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<br>
 <table id="myTable" class="test1" border="1" style="border-collapse:collapse">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name2</th>
            <th>Sports2</th>
            <th>Country2</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Sachin Tendulkar2</td>
            <td>Cricket2</td>
            <td>India2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Tiger Woods2</td>
            <td>Golf2</td>
            <td>USA2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Maria Sharapova2</td>
            <td>Tennis2</td>
            <td>Russia2</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/aPLLF/66/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `not()` to exclude the table with the ID...

```
$("table").not($("#myTable"));
```

That will return all tables except the one with the specified ID.

Looking at your example code, though, this is all you need to update to make it work...

```
$("table:not(#myTable) tbody>tr").hide();
```

Comment: Thanks!  That was a great answer!  It definitely answers the question I asked.  However, my fiddle was a very simplified version of what I am trying to achieve.  What if there are more than 2 tables?  My actual application has more than I care to count at the moment, all with different id's and classes.  :)

Similar to: http://jsfiddle.net/aPLLF/72/

Comment: You can use as many `:not()` identifiers as you like... http://jsfiddle.net/qzqyf/

Answer (score 1):

A quick solution is to change:

```
$("tbody>tr").hide();
```

to

```
$("table:not(':first') tbody>tr").hide();
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/aPLLF/67/)**

Answer (score 0):

Target tables with an id

```
$("table[id] tbody>tr").hide();
```

or any classes

```
$("table[id] tbody>tr").hide();
```

without an id

```
$("table:not([id]) tbody>tr").hide();
```

without any classes

```
$("table:not([class]) tbody>tr").hide();
```